# Refresh a page only when the browser is not minimized and the tab is active

Tags: javascript, browser-refresh

Could you tell me how to do an autorefresh (every minute) on a page.

The refresh should only occur when the browser is not minimized and the tab is active.
When the browser is restored(unminimized) do a refresh, if the page with the refresh is active.

Example: I have 2 tabs, one on "YouTube" and the other on myApplication, there is a refresh only if the myApplication's tab is active.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)